# CakePHP 3: Generate shortened url (canonical)

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, redirect

I'm tryng to prevent duplicated content.
My posts original url are like this:

> domain.com/post/52-quick-brown-fox-jumps-over-lazy-dog

I want to generate a shortened url and use them to share in, for example, twitter

> domain.com/p/52 ----> redirects to ---> original url

How can do this? Via htaccess 301 redirect? Via CakePHP Routing?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I've already edited!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The redirect itself should be a 301 (moved permanently), so all the links to the short urls are mapped to the long urls in the google index.

The Router class has an own `redirect` method. You basically duplicate your actual route, replace `connect` with `redirect` and change the url pattern to match your short url:

```
$routes->redirect('/p/:id', ['controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'display'], [
    'pass' => ['id'],
    'status' => 301,
    'persist' => true
]);
$routes->connect('/post/:id-:slug', ['controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'display'], [
    'pass' => ['id', 'slug']
]);
```

The only downside: You will, to my knowledge, not be able to generate the short urls from the Router class, because it will always generate the long url from the passed parameters. You would have to generate them manually from the `id`.

Be sure that the Controller checks for the presence of the correct slug and performs a redirect to the correct url if it is not. You can use the [Controllers `redirect()` method](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#redirecting-to-other-pages).

```
public function display($id, $slug = null) {
    $post = $this->Posts->findById($id);
    if($post) {
        if($post->slug !== $slug) {
            return $this->redirect('/post/' . urlencode($id . '-' . $slug), 301);
        }
        //Other stuff
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error('The post was not found.');
        return $this->redirect('/posts');
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid the double redirect, you might want to use `connect` instead of `redirect` (thanks to [ndm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392379/ndm) for that comment):

```
$routes->connect('/p/:id', ['controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'display'], [
    'pass' => ['id'],
    'status' => 301
]);
$routes->connect('/post/:id-:slug', ['controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'display'], [
    'pass' => ['id', 'slug']
]);
```

The Controller should still redirect to the correct url if the slug is wrong or absent.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I added your concerns to my answer.

Comment: This still needs a little tweak I think, as it's not clear that the controller (I guess it's debatable whether the routing layer may be more appropriate) needs to resolve the `id` to get the `slug` and finally redirect to the desired "expanded" URL. And it looks like you've interchanged the `pass` values ;)

Comment: Indeed I did. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Thanks guys! I think it's work fine. Now, I just have to check if the redirects is really a 301. I'm going to edit the question and post the solution for all.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**

config/routes.php

```
//slug url format, in my case .com/p/id
$routes->connect(
    '/p/:id',
    ['controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'view'],
    [
        'pass' => ['id', 'slug'],
        'id' => '[0-9]+',
        'status' => 301
    ]
);
```

PostsController.php

```
// If slug is null, redirect to the full post url
public function view($id=null, $slug=null)
{
    $post = $this->Posts->get($id);
    if( is_null($slug) ) {
        $this->redirect('/post/'.$post->id.'-'.$post->slug, 301);
    }
    $this->set(compact('post'));
}
```

Comment: `if( is_null($slug) ) {` <- that should rather be `if ($post->slug != $slug)`. This was one of the points raised in the other answer, otherwise any slug works. It would also be a better idea to use reverse routing (define the url as an array) instead of redirecting to a string.